# Flutter why does futureBuilder consider null firestore document as not null?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
 FutureBuilder(future: Firestore.instance
            .collection('items')
            .document('itemId')
            .collection('sold')
            .document('sold')
            .get(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              return (snapshot != null) ? Text(
                '${snapshot.data['sold']}'
              ) : Text('not sold');}
```

I wrote this code here using futureBuilder, expecting the widget to show "not sold" when the "sold" field of document "sold" on firestore has no value yet("sold" document not created yet).

But when it's obvious that the snapshot is null, since the document is not created, it proceeds the first option of ternary and try to output '${snapshot.data['sold']}', showing this error

```
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("sold")
```

Seems it takes "snapshot.data" from '${snapshot.data['sold']}' as null which is correct since there is no document created yet, but I can't figure out why it does not consider snapshot from '(snapshot != null)' not null.

And when there is "sold" document created and it's not null, it show the '${snapshot.data['sold']}' value on the screen alright.

Only ternary is not working here..

I searched for it and tried with "(snapshot.hasdata)" instead of "(snapshot != null)" but nothing changed.

What am I doing wrong here?

PS - it seems the document is actually null but somehow considered as if it's not null. I don't know whether it's the problem with firestore side, or maybe futureBuilder is built to initialize with some initial data state..

Comment: I didn't.  I just reformatted the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
builder: (context, snapshot){
          return (snapshot.data != null) ? Text(
            '${snapshot.data['sold']}'
          ) : Text('not sold');}
```

another way is:

```
builder: (context, snapshot){
          return (snapshot.hasData) ? Text(
            '${snapshot.data['sold']}'
          ) : Text('not sold');}
```

you can check for errors as well, maybe that's what's missing

```
builder: (context, snapshot){
          if (snapshot.hasError) return Text("Error");
          if (snapshot.hasData) return Text(snapshot.data['sold']);
          // else return a progress indicator
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
}
```

Comment: using "snapshot.data" and "snapshot.hasData" gives the same result. Somehow it considers the null data not null. That's the problem..

Comment: @AndyYoung I updated the answer with another code snippet, hopefully, this one works and you can find the problem

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Omar, you can try that way or even you can try something like the below

```
builder: (context, snapshot){
              return (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null && snapshot.data.lenght > 0) ? Text(
                '${snapshot.data['sold']}'
              ) : Text('not sold');}
```

Comment: It made no difference. I think the problem is it considering null data as not null..any ideas on it?

Comment: I think that you first should be sure that your futurebuilder is null. Have you tried to print it? This could be a good idea to know what is the content of it and then you can verify why it has that value